# babel 7, IE > 9, webpack 3, IE Syntax error for ES6

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs, babel-polyfill

I am not able to get arrow functions, even:

() => 1 * 1; working in IE 9 and IE 11 using Babel 7, it works in chrome,     rest and destructuring works in Chrome but the following are not working in IE 9 or IE 11, arrow-functions, destructuring, rest.

The code is set up as follows:

package.json file:

```
devDependencies:
        "@babel/cli": "^7.1.0",
        "@babel/core": "^7.0.0",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.1.0",
        "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
        "@babel/preset-stage-0": "^7.0.0",
        "@babel/preset-stage-3": "^7.0.0",
        "babel-loader": "^8.0.0",

dependencies: 
"@babel/polyfill": "^7.0.0"


Running with webpack 3.8.1.

.babelrc file is simply:

{
"presets":  [
    ["@babel/preset-env", {
        "targets": {
            "browsers": ["ie >= 9"]
        },
        "esmodules": true,
        "loose": true,
        "debug": true,
        "useBuiltIns": "entry"
    }],
    "@babel/preset-stage-0"],
"plugins": [
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-import-meta",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-arrow-functions",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-object-assign",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-json-strings"
],
"ignore": [
    "node_modules"
]
}
```

webpack.js file:

entries in webpack.js:

```
entry: {
        commonThirdParty: ['@babel/polyfill', 'backbone', 'lodash'],
},

module: {
    loaders: [{
                    test: /.js?$/,
                    include: odfPath,
                    exclude: /(node_modules|node)/,
                    use: [{
                        loader: 'babel-loader',
                    }]
    }]
}
```

Does any body have any ideas, how I can get IE 9 & IE 11 to accept ES6 code transpiled to ES5 to work successfully?

Comment: "() => 1 * 1; working in IE 9 and IE 11" is the opposite of "following are not working in IE 9 or IE 11, arrow-functions". Which one is it?

Comment: What is `odfPath`? If `include` doesn't include the file with the arrow functions in, it'll not get passed through Babel.

Comment: - arrow functions are not working in IE 9 and IE 11 eg:

    () => 1 * 1;  returns syntax error.

odfPath is: like:
C:\path\to\design-framework\src\ui

Comment: any ideas, anyone?